# Error al iniciar app android recién instalada en el dispositivo

Tags: android

Tengo una aplicación de productividad publicada en Google Play.

El problema es que cuando se descarga y no se inicia desde la página de instalación de Google Play, aparece el mensaje de aplicación detenida.

Por el contrario, si se instala y se inicia desde las descargas e instalación de Google Play funciona sin dar más problemas.

¿Podríais darme alguna pista de lo que puede estar ocurriendo? Gracias por vuestra atención.

Comment: Has mirado tema permisos del teléfono referente a aplicaciones externas de la App store?

Comment: La app está publicada en Google Play, no es externa y tampoco necesita permisos. Gracias por responder.

Comment: ¿La aplicación es tuya o es de una tercera persona? Hay aplicaciones que comprueban en su código el origen de instalación de la aplicación y su no es Google Play cesan su funcionamiento. Si es tuya la aplicación entonces debemos buscar otros orígenes, comenzando por depurar la aplicación desde, por ejemplo, android studio.

Comment: Has revisado los métodos, `views` y `styles` implementados?, has probado en dispositivos distintos o en solo una versión especifica de `Android`? ya por allí puedes comenzar a descartar, probando con otras densidades y versiones de `Android` en el emulador. Esto con el fin de verificar que no sea algún tipo de incompatibilidad.

Comment: OscarGarcía gracias por contestar. Como comprenderás antes de publicarla ya la depuré en varios dispositivos y simuladores distintos, no tuve problemas.

Comment: David Villegas gracias por contestar. La respuesta a OscarGarcía creo que responde a tu sugerencia.

Comment: Conecta el dispositivo a Android Studio, ejecutá la app de modo que se produzca el crash, y fijate que tira logcat. Luego agrega el error a la pregunta para ver de que se trata.

Comment: @JAS no es lo mismo, yo hablo de incompatibilidades de versiones de estilos y métodos que se usan a partir de un `API` especifico en dispositivos `Android`

Comment: Juan, si se produjera el cuelgue en los emuladores en los que la he probado no estaría preguntando aquí. Está probada con todas las APIs y dispositivos emulados que soporta, además de otros reales. Gracias por contestar.